# h2 default DECIMAL precision performance

Tags: sql, precision, h2, database-performance

When I create `DECIMAL` column with default precision setting, in H2 web console this column is defined as `DECIMAL(65535, 32767)`, command "show columns from ..." gives me `DECIMAL(65535)`.

Decimal data type in H2 is mapped to `BigDecimal` (from H2 documentation), but I'm not sure how H2 deals with it.

Are there any performance gains, if I use smaller precision?

Comment: DO you really need 65535 integer digits and 32767 fraction digits? Is that what you intended by this declaration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get to know more about the `DECIMAL` datatype of H2, inspect the `org.h2.value.ValueDecimal` class that comes with the `h2-x.y.z.jar`.

Taking a closer look you'll see the default values are as you mentioned:

```
/** The default precision for a decimal value. */
static final int DEFAULT_PRECISION = 65535;
/** The default scale for a decimal value.     */
static final int DEFAULT_SCALE = 32767;
```

Looking closer in `ValueDecimal`:

```
private final BigDecimal value;
```

and `org.h2.store.Data`:

```
public Value readValue() {
    ...
    case Value.DECIMAL: {
        int scale = readVarInt();
        int len = readVarInt();
        byte[] buff = DataUtils.newBytes(len);
        read(buff, 0, len);
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(buff);
        return ValueDecimal.get(new BigDecimal(b, scale));
    }
```

You can see that a `DECIMAL` is nothing more than a `BigDecimal`. That is, all the performance issues you'll face with `java.math.BigDecimal`, you'll face with `DECIMAL`.

If you are really into it, you can study the class further and see what exact role the precision/scale play.

If we go to the docs, all H2 say about `DECIMAL` data types and performance is:

> The `DECIMAL`/`NUMERIC` type is slower and requires more storage than the `REAL` and `DOUBLE` types.

So they say that is a fact.

But since you are talking about performance, we can cut to the chase and do some tests. The test class' code is below, let's get to the output/results:

```
TYPE              INSERT time    COUNT() time   .db Size (kb)  
DECIMAL(20,2)     6.978          0.488          27958.0        
DECIMAL(100,2)    4.879          0.407          25648.0        
DECIMAL(100,80)   8.794          0.868          90818.0        
DECIMAL(60000,2)  4.388          0.4            25104.0        
DECIMAL(1000,900) 112.905        6.549          1016534.0      
REAL              5.938          0.318          22608.0        
DOUBLE            6.985          0.416          25088.0
```

As you can see, there is no noticeable change in the time or storage size when the precision changes (precision `20` takes roughly as much time/size as `60000`!).

The thing is when you change the **scale**. This is what you should worry about; as you can see, `DECIMAL(100,2)` and `DECIMAL(100,80)` show a great increase in both time and storage.

`DECIMAL(1000,900)` takes more than **1 gigabyte**(!!!) storing absolutely the same values.

Finally, in the test above, `REAL` and `DOUBLE` don't seem to be so much better than `DECIMAL` (they may even seem worse). But try changing the number of lines inserted (the `for` loop in the test method), the bigger the number, the better they seem to respond.

<sup>* `DECIMAL(20,2)` seems to be slower/larger than the rest. That is not real. Actually, whatever you choose to run first is going to be slightly slower/larger. Go figure...</sup>

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        System.out.format("%-18s%-15s%-15s%-15s", "TYPE", "INSERT time", "COUNT() time", ".db Size (kb)");
        System.out.println();
        testPerformance("TEST_DECIMAL_20_2",     "DECIMAL(20,2)");
        testPerformance("TEST_DECIMAL_100_2",    "DECIMAL(100,2)");
        testPerformance("TEST_DECIMAL_100_80",   "DECIMAL(100,80)");
        testPerformance("TEST_DECIMAL_60000_2",  "DECIMAL(60000,2)");
        testPerformance("TEST_DECIMAL_1000_900", "DECIMAL(1000,900)");
        testPerformance("TEST_REAL",             "REAL");
        testPerformance("TEST_DOUBLE",           "DOUBLE"); 
    }

    private static void testPerformance(String dbName, String type) throws SQLException {
        System.out.format("%-18s", type);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:" + dbName, "sa", "");
        conn.createStatement().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST;");
        conn.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE TEST (DECTEST " + type +" )");
        long insertStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            conn.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO TEST (DECTEST) VALUES (12345678901234.45)");    
        }
        double insertTime = ((double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-insertStartTime))/1000;
        System.out.format("%-15s", insertTime+"");
        long countStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select COUNT(DECTEST) from TEST");
        double countTime = ((double)(System.currentTimeMillis()-countStartTime))/1000;
        System.out.format("%-15s", countTime+"");
        conn.close();
        double fileSize = (double)new File(dbName+".h2.db").length() / 1024;
        System.out.format("%-15s", fileSize+"");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The precision and scale of `DECIMAL` is optional in H2. If you create the column without specifying precision / scale, then performance is not affected, storage is not affected, and you can insert any value and will get the same value back:

```
create table test(data decimal);
insert into test values(1.345);
select * from test;
> 1.345
```